# TinyXpath v_get_xpath_base, second parameter

Tags: c++, tinyxpath

What do I pass here as the second parameter to [v_get_xpath_base](http://tinyxpath.sourceforge.net/doc/classTinyXPath_1_1xpath__processor.html#a8) in order to get it to work, no matter what I try, there always seems to be a problem.  Either the class is a base class and cannot be instantiated or the class cannot be casted.

I'm at a loss, someone help me please?

```
        TiXmlElement* outputnode = new TiXmlElement("test");
  bool isAttrib;
  proc.v_get_xpath_base(1, outputnode, isAttrib);
```

As it currently stands, the `TiXmlElement` cannot be cast to `const TiXmlBase*&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is going to return you the matching node - I imagine you need something like:

```
const TiXmlBase* outputnode(0);
bool isAttrib;
proc.v_get_xpath_base(1, outputnode, isAttrib);
```

and after the call, `outputNode` will point to the matched data.  Seems like you have to use `const TiXmlBase*` as the type for `outputnode`.  There is a sample [here](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid8C5450648D701EFDEF18E020AC4DCC072D67E149.aspx?s=mdef%3atree) that does this.

Note that this only works after you have done this, per the TinyXml docs:

> Can only be used after a call to
>   u_compute_xpath_node_set.

Comment: my compiler says:: cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const TiXmlElement *' to 'const TiXmlBase *& '

Comment: Did you try `const TiXmlBase* outputnode(0);`?  I don't have the library, so cannot try this.

Comment: @Tony - see edit, I found a sample that uses `TiXmlBase` and casts the result to what is needed. Edited reply accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
Steve solution works fine but I don't see how to use `outputnode` after.
It cannot be cast from `TiXmlBase` to `TiXmlElement` nor be directly used with method from this child class.
I'm browsing the documentation without finding a way to manipulate this `TiXmlBase` pointer.